# Is there a way to paint semi transparently on a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I use a transparent background for the `PictureBox` control.

But I also want to be able to paint with a %50 opacity blue `FillRectangle`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET WinForm controls themselves do not support transparency, but GDI+ does as far as general rendering goes.  If you are rendering onto a PictureBox (or onto anything else) and want to render something with partial opacity, then create a color with an alpha value less then 255 (opaque) and use it to create a brush or pen.

For example:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Blue);
using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(c))
{
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: Yeah the PictureBox is rather limited. You might have to start doing your own OnPaint event.